# powerbi programmatically replace CSV source in PBIX

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm looking for the method to reduce time needed to update visuals in PowerBI WEB.

My current process is:

1. Generate CSV data - it takes roughly 1 minute and outputs 10 mln rows
2. Push that data to Azure SQL server - it takes 45 minutes
3. Press Refresh button in PowerBI web - reports use import from Azure SQL and it takes few minutes to refresh visuals

So ... timing is rather long, around 50+ minutes.

Alternative way I think about is:

1. Programmatically update data in local PBIX, manually via UI it take around 30-50 seconds
2. Programmatically upload PBIX to WEB (I know REST API exists), manually it takes around 10-20 seconds

This way will reduce update time from 50 minutes to 1-2 minute, but ... I could not find the way to implement #1 "Programmatically update data in local PBIX". Is this possible somehow?

Other ideas regarding how to speed up refresh of data in Powerbi WEB are welcome too.

Answer (score 1):

There's no API to automate refresh in Power BI Desktop.  The intended process in this scenario is to have the Power BI Service refresh the Dataset directly, using an [On-Prem Gateway](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/gateway/) if the data source is not directly accessible.

So load the Dataset directly from the data source, or from the exported CSV.